# To place in comparison or to put in comparison

Tags: word-choice, phrases

Which one is correct, "to put in comparison" or "to place in comparison"?

Comment: Outside of any meaningfull context both sound unnatural; could you supply some?

Comment: This is the sentence I'm not sure about:

to place two things in comparison

Comment: It may technically be a sentence, but what is the context that comes before? As I said neither sounds right on its own - we need to know where it fits-in with what you're trying to communicate. Failing that you might want to join our sister site [ell.se].

Comment: There's no context, and this may also be the reason why this sentence sounds weird to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idiomatic phrase that  expresses what you appear to have in mind would be "**set a comparison between**". Here is an example ot its [use](https://books.google.fr/books?id=K6u53Amm7xIC&pg=PA142&dq=%22set+a+comparison%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj31JqDpLjoAhWSHxQKHbhAA7kQ6AEIhQEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22set%20a%20comparison%22&f=false).

The chapter applies this framework on 2 public organizations in Egypt to test it and *to set a comparison between both organizations* in terms of the internal factors effect on e-Government readiness.  (*user LPH's italics*)

Comment: Otherwise, I think, we should just compare; neither put nor place.